# API call using Postman returns CAPTCHA?

Tags: api, postman, captcha

I need to examine GraphQL API using Postman.

When I send request, it returns this CAPTCHA response.
[image]

I am not sure about the reason. Can anybody help me to know the reason and how to pass it?

I'd be grateful why this kind of thing often happens on my browser and even on Postman.

Comment: This is configured by the server to disallow programmatic API calls.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually other people use postman to test it but such thing never happened.

Comment: Same question https://stackoverflow.com/q/71934236/196526