# How to deal with captcha check with API and Postman?

Tags: api, postman, cloudflare

I use Postman to test an API (The API of brickset.com). Whe calling my https://brickset.com/api/v3.asmx/login?apiKey=xxx&username=xxx&password=xxx I get the HTML page of cloudflare captcha verification. When doing the same GET in my browser (Edge) I had the captcha page the first time then now I get the correct result.

How can I whitelist my IP or whitelist my Postman app or get the cookie or whatever I need to make sure that when I send my request I bypass this robot verification page?

[image]

## New information

After testing Postman again with my VPN connected to Hong Kong first, then Belgium.

On Hong Kong, where I live, the request response is this captcha page.
On Belgium, with VPN, the request response with correct JSON.

What is this? How Can I tell this cloudflare system they can trust my IP ? I'm lucky I have a VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you own `brickset.com`, you can definitely whitelist your IP through Cloudflare dashboard; brickset.com > Security > WAF -> Tools, and then add your IP.

Since you mentioned it's an API, you probably want to disable *Browser Integrity Check* so you don't get captcha on API calls for normal browser calls as well (read more about it [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200504045-Using-Cloudflare-with-your-API)).

Can't say how Cloudflare's captcha or anti-bot works. Multiple factors such as public IP reputation, number of requests, User Agent, ...etc, could trigger the captcha page.

Comment: I do not own brickset.com... of course not. I already send an email to breakset.com but they seems very difficul to contact. I had to contact them on Twitter. I created my account on twitter for them.

Comment: I see. Well, it's partly their issue for having the Browser Integrity Check on their API. For now what you can do is, set User Agent exactly like what your browser does. If you're still getting captcha, then yeah, you'll have to rotate your IPs. Reputation of IP/ASN does matter. If you've bad neighbors, you can get captchas more often. Proxies and VPN will help you there. Perhaps you should consider hosting your app on a server, assuming you're currently on local.